# Filtering out certain strings from standard input

Tags: linux, unix

I need a Unix command that will take piped input, filter out certain strings and write the rest to standard output. The catch is that it needs to be a one-line command that doesn't depend on anything that doesn't ship out of the box in a typical Linux distribution.

The context is that 'llvm-config --libs' links in a couple of test files that it shouldn't, and I need to eliminate those - but I need to do it from within configure.ac.

And the twist is that it's not one item per line, it's all items on the same line, separated by spaces not newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) is a pretty common Unix/Linux command, at least I've yet to come across any distro's that I've had to specifically install the basic `grep` (vs. say `egrep` or another filter command).

> take piped input, filter out certain strings and write the rest to standard output.

To use it like that to filter it out, you could do the following (assuming you're using `cat` to print a file to standard output)

```
cat "some_file.txt" | grep -v "text to omit"
```

Additionally, `grep` also works on files as well, so the above command could just be written as such:

```
grep -v "text to omit" "some_file.txt"
```

The `-v` flag tells `grep` to print everything *except* the specified text. If you want a case in-sensitive search you would need to specify the `-i` flag.

> it's not one item per line, it's all items on the same line, separated by spaces not newlines.

To this, you could add a for loop to iterate over the words and still utilize grep to achieve what you're needing, example:

```
for word in "hello there how" are you how "am i today"; do echo $word; done | grep -v "how"
```

The output for this would be:

```
are
you
am i today
```

And to have it output on a single line you can use the [`tr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) command to translate the `\n` to a space:

```
for word in "hello there how" are you how "am i today"; do echo $word; done | grep -v how | tr '\n' ' '
```

Here the output would be:

```
are you am i today
```

The first part of `for word in` is the shell scripting [`for loop`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html). The link provided is specific to `BASH` but the syntax is pretty similar among the other shells (at least for `CSH`, `KSH` and `ASH`), so you might have to adjust to have the syntax match your specific shell.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Ah! It would indeed if the input were one item per line, but it's not, it's all the items on the same line, separated by spaces not newlines. I'd better add that as a clarification to the question.

Comment: @rwallace, updated my answer for your updated question :)

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising! Is there a way to turn the output back into single line format afterwards? Or since it needs to end up in a makefile, maybe I could do something like appending a backslash to each line.

Comment: ... sadly, appending a backslash to each line doesn't work, because it has to omit the backslash from the last line.

Comment: Modified answer again, just pipe that output to `tr` .. eg: `for word in blah blah blah; do echo $word; done | grep -v omit | tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: That works now, thanks! (Well, the build still doesn't, but that's because there is some other problem; this particular part of it does.)